# how to find user full name in domain from service running with system account in c#

Tags: c#

I have service running with system account I found below code which gives proper user name when run with user account and gives error when run with system account. could someone help how to check logged in user full name when service is running with system account.

```
private static string GetFullName()
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.UserDomainName + "/" + Environment.UserName);
        return de.Properties["fullName"].Value.ToString();
    }
    catch { return null; }
}
```

**Answer:** Instead of using Environment.UserDomainName + "/" + Environment.UserName I manually passed the domain and username and it is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can get first name and last name separately and then can return as below,

```
private static string GetFullName()
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.UserDomainName + "/" + Environment.UserName);
        return de.Properties["FullName"].Value.ToString();
    }
    catch { return null; }
}
```

Comment: I think it is not able to find the "givenName" property. it is giving error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Let me double check

Comment: I have updated it, please have a look, it's actually "FullName" and the old code will work for `LDAP` connection and "FullName" work for `WinNT`

Comment: no luck, it is the same code which I have given. it will work when the exe is running with user account. it will give error when running with system account.

Comment: Is your system account is local account or domain account? and how do you run this code, windows service, then can you me a sample domain and system account name?

Comment: it is a windows service running on machine with local machine system account and not domain system account.

Comment: Yes thats why it throws error. Have you defined the full name for the account and also you should remove this, `Environment.UserDomainName`

Comment: Why you need full name of the local system account. If you need then you should assign a valid user account by selecting `This account` on the `Log On` tab of the `Properties` dialog

Comment: what I did is provided domain name and username to the above method and now it is giving proper  output.

Comment: @Farhan great :-)